# Regex to parse multiline data

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, multiline

I have a following data from a file and I would like to see if I can do a regex parsing here

```
Name (First Name)   City       Zip
John (retired)                 10007
Mark                Baltimore  21268
....
....
Avg Salary
70000               100%
```

Its not a big file and the entire data from the file is available in a String object with a new line characters (\n) (String data = "data from the file")

1. I am trying to get name, city, zip and then the salary, percentage details
2. data inside () considered part of Name field.
3. For Name field space is considered valid and there are no space for other fields.
4. 'Avg Salary' is available only at the end of the file

Will it be easy to do this via regex parsing in Java?

Comment: And what are you trying to parse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621252/how-to-split-a-file-into-multiple-arrays-display-them-and-perform-calculations/20621864#20621864 this would help

Comment: I am trying to get name, city, zip and then the salary, percentage details

Comment: Is the data inside the round brackets `()` considered part of the `Name` field? Are spaces considered valid characters for these fields?

Comment: It's a bit unclear of what do you want to get. Is the data hand-aligned (meaning, there are space characters to align the data to the respective column heading)? Is the "Avg Salary" information available only at the end of the String?

Comment: @Daemon: data inside () considered part of Name field. For Name field space is considered valid and there are not space for other fields.

Comment: @justhalf: its a generated file. And yes there are space characters to align the data to the respective column heading. Yes, 'Avg Salary' is available only at the end of the file. Is it too much to do regex parsing?

Comment: It may be possible to use a regex to solve this problem, but it's not yet clear what the problem is. Are you hoping to use a single regex to parse _all_ the names, cities and zip codes, along with the average salary at the end of the file?

Comment: @qwrrty - Single regex would be good. If that is too complicated, splitting the data into separate lines and do regex parsing would be okay as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the text file is space-aligned, you can (and probably should) extract the fields based on the number of characters. So, you take the first `n` characters in each line as first name, the next `m` characters as City, and so on.

This is one code to extract using the above method, by calculating the field length of the fields automatically, assuming we know the header.

```
String data = "data from the file";

// This is just to ensure we have enough space in the array
int numNewLines = data.length()-data.replace("\n","").length();
String[][] result = new String[numNewLines][3];
String[] lines = data.split("\n");
int avgSalary = 0;
int secondFieldStart = lines[0].indexOf("City");
int thirdFieldStart = lines[0].indexOf("Zip");
for(int i=1; i<lines.length; i++){
    String line = lines[i].trim();
    if(line.equals("Avg Salary")){
        avgSalary = Integer.parseInt(lines[i+1].substring(0,secondFieldStart).trim());
        break;
    }
    result[i-1][0] = line.substring(0,secondFieldStart).trim(); // First Name
    result[i-1][1] = line.substring(secondFieldStart,thirdFieldStart).trim(); // City
    result[i-1][2] = line.substring(thirdFieldStart).trim(); // Zip
}
```

Using regex will be possible, but it will be more complicated. And regex won't be able to differentiate person's name and city's name anyway:

Consider this case:

```
John Long-name Joe New York   21003
```

How would you know the name is `John Long-name Joe` instead of `John Long-name Joe New` if you don't know that the length of the first field is at most 20 characters? (note that length of `John Long-name Joe` is 19 characters, leaving one space between it and `New` in `New York`)

Of course if your fields are separated by other characters (like tab character `\t`), you can split each line based on that. And it's easy to modify the code above to accommodate that =)

Since the solution I proposed above is simpler, I guess you might want to try it instead =)

Comment: Thx! Although it will work now, parsing based on the a fixed length might not work always in future. A small change(more spaces or removal of spaces) in the text file will break the code.

Comment: You can try to "learn" the number of spaces required from the header also, if you want. Because otherwise it's impossible for the regex to differentiate person's name and city name. You will still need some character-based constraint anyway.

Comment: You can check my edits on recognizing field lengths.